# Views: Sort By Global Math Expression Result?

Tags: entities, views

I have created a global math expression field in views, and I want to sort the results by the results of the math expression.

In particular, I use Drealty to connect to a RETS server and download property listings.  My local database gets populated with prices and number of bedrooms for each listing.  I want to sort based on Cost per Bedroom.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't sort currently by just using views but i would recommend to store
the value in the database.

Therefore create a computed field: http://drupal.org/project/computed_field
and do the logic in there to store the value in the DB. Once you have done this views will be able to sort by that.

Answer (score 1):

If you have [table with aggregation module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator) you can sort without needing to store in DB

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do it by creating a new module with hook_drealty_import_presave_alter or rules.  The problem is that you need to write the result of the math to the database so that you can sort or filter on it.